# Why do I need to run a file several times in MATLAB before it stops throwing an error?

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to debug this weird bug where I run a script in matlab and it says that it cannot find some function that I have clearly defined in a folder and also obviously imported to the running script. However, after running the script a few times it suddenly accepts it knows where the location of my function is and runs. I find this really strange because that shouldn't be happening because imports are deterministic functions, so I have no idea why running it multiple times should make a difference.

---

To reproduce my bug you can find my code in my project's [github page](https://github.com/brando90/research). Go/cd to the folder:

`research/HBF_mat_lib/HBF1_multivariant_regression/om_simulations/h_add_cv`

and

run:

`test_debug_script`

in MATLAB.

It show throw an error:

```
Undefined function 'learn_HBF1_SGD' for input
arguments of type 'HBF1_parameters'.

Error in get_best_trained_hbf1_model (line 37)
        [ mdl_params, errors_train, errors_test ] =
        train_func( X_train, y_train, mdl_params,
        iterations,visualize, X_test,y_test,
        eta_c,eta_t, sgd_errors);

Error in test_debug_script (line 11)
    get_best_trained_hbf1_model(slurm_job_id,
    task_id)

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

but if you try running it enough times it runs as it should.

---

Things I've tried to clear this bug is clear my matlab environment, restore my path to normal, at this point I have no idea what I can do because I have also printed out what path is before executing stuff and the folder seems to be in my path variable. At this point I have no idea what I can do and why after running a few times it runs, it should ALWAYS fail but it does not...

Comment: @TroyHaskin ur a saviour (I think it works now). Can I thank you by at least upvoting ur comment as an answer? Though, it still puzzles me why it works even if I just run that script a couple of times. Thats still mysterious to me.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I see the error now but why didn't matlab point to that point in the code saying like "that function doesn't exists so I can't get the handle/pointer to it". So bizzare.

Comment: I upgraded my comment to an answer since it worked.  As for the function handle checking for the existence of the file, that is more of a feature than a detriment.  I mean, the function could exist in the future, so why not allow a syntactically correct reference that will only error when it is invoked?  In truth, anytime you see an "Undefined function" error, you first thought should be "is it on the path?".

Comment: @TroyHaskin totally agree, I should ask that. Thats why I printed path before it was allowed to run. It said there it was on my path so I had no idea why it was a issue. In fact, Im still confused how ur suggestion solved it if later the folder where my function was located was in my path :/

Answer (score 2):

I'd venture it's because you're creating a reference to `learn_HBF1_SGD` in `simulation_config.m` before you put the function on the Matlab path via `load_paths.m`, which you've made dependent on the function handle's content. Given the current structure, I'd switch to declaring `train_func_name` explicitly, and then use `str2func` to create the handle after the paths have been loaded.

Subsequent runs of the file work because the execution did not stop until after the calls to [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) have been made.  And since `addpath` "adds the specified folders to the top of the search path for the current MATLAB® session", the function was on the Matlab path for subsequent runs.

Comment: but I had resotredpath, so my path was reset every time, but eventually it still worked, which is why this bug is really mysterious. I hope ur suggestion does solve it. No issue yet. Though , thnx for takin a look at it.

Comment: @CharlieParker That is odd, and I forgot to look into that.  Apparently, recent versions of Matlab changed `restoredefaultpath.m` to [restores the user path](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63633-restoredefaultpath-doesn-t-restore-default-path-rather-restores-user-s-path).  I'm not sure if you save the path anywhere, but this may be the source of that problem.  I'd recommend a solution using `rmpath` for more control.